# A question about limit 22

Tags: limits

Given two differentiable functions $f$ and $g$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that
$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L$, where $a$ and $L$ may be any real number or $\infty$.

Question:

Is it necessary that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)= L \cdot \lim _{x \to a} g(x)$?

Comment: If $L=\infty$ then expressions like $L.c$ don't make sense.

Comment: How about $f=x-a, g=(x-a)^2, L=\infty$? $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f=\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g=0,$ but what is the value of $\infty\cdot 0$?

Comment: what does the title of this post mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple main reasons why this need not follow.

1. $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ need not exist! Consider something like $a=\infty$, $f(x)=g(x)=\sin(x)+2$ (the $+2$ is so that $g(x)$ isn't $0$). Then $L=1$ but both of the other limits diverge due to oscillation. Since $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are differentiable, they're continuous at every real $a$, so you can't have counterexamples where $a$ is real and the limits of $f$ and $g$ don't exist.
2. As drhab and Shine point out, if $L=\infty$, then multiplying by $L$ doesn't really make sense. Even if you pick a convention like $0*\infty=0$, you're not going to end up with the right answer all the time. If $f(x)=17$ and $g(x)=\begin{cases}
   x^2 & \text{ if }x\ne0\\5 & \text{ if }x=0
   \end{cases}$ and $a=0$, we would need $17=\infty*0$ (this sort of thing is why $\infty*0$ is [indeterminate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).

---

Now, a standard calculus fact says that *if* both $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$, $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exist, and the latter is not zero, then $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\lim_{x\to a}f(x)}{\lim_{x\to a}g(x)}$. Then you can just multiply both sides by $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ to get your result.

Comment: The OP stipulates that $f$ and $g$ are *differentiable* functions, so the funky examples with $a=0$ don't really apply.

Comment: @BarryCipra Whoops! Well that's boring. Thanks; I'll edit.